# Pandas - "select where a condition exists" between two columns of different dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```py
data1 = {
    'id': [1,1,2,2],
    'tag': [700,800,700,800],
    'Membership': [1,0.9,0.8,0.7],
}
data2 = {
    'id': [1,2,3,3],
    'tag': [700,800,600,500],
    'Membership': [0.5,0.9,0.8,0.7],
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

Which looks like:

```py
>>> df1
      id   tag  Membership
0      1   700         1.0
1      1   800         0.9
2      2   700         0.8
3      2   800         0.7

>>> df2
      id   tag  Membership
0      1   700         0.5
1      2   800         0.9
2      3   600         0.8
3      3   500         0.7
```

I want to **add rows from df1 to df2, where the combination of `(id,tag)` doesn't exist in df2**.
So, any rows without the condition of `df1['id'] == df2['id'] and df1['tag'] == df2['tag']` should be added to df2:

```py
>>> df2
      id   tag  Membership
0      1   700         0.5
1      2   800         0.9
2      3   600         0.8
3      3   500         0.7
4      1   800         0.9  # This row added
5      2   700         0.8  # This row added
```

#### What I've tried:

I tried to find the rows where my condition is not true, then appending the result to df2:

```py
new_rows = df1[~((df1['id'] == df2['id']) & (df1['tag'] == df2['tag']))]
df2 = df2.append(new_rows).reset_index(drop=True)
```

But as you can see, I'm getting wrong result, because (id,tag) pair of (2,800) already exists in df2. why is that?

```py
>>> df2
      id   tag  Membership
0      1   700         0.5
1      2   800         0.9
2      3   600         0.8
3      3   500         0.7
4      1   800         0.9  # correct
5      2   700         0.8  # correct
6      2   800         0.7  # THIS SHOULDN't BE ADDED
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html#pandas-dataframe-combine-first):

```py
indices = ['id', 'tag']
left = df2.set_index(indices)
right = df1.set_index(indices)
combined = left.combine_first(right).reset_index()
combined
```

Result:

```
   id  tag  Membership
0   1  700         0.5
1   1  800         0.9
2   2  700         0.8
3   2  800         0.9
4   3  500         0.7
5   3  600         0.8
```

Comment: Could you explain how it works? So I can choose it as accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

The equality operator that you're using in this condition:

```
(df1['id'] == df2['id']) & (df1['tag'] == df2['tag'])
```

is not the right tool for this job, it doesn't work like you expect, it compares the dataframes row by row. Let's start with a simpler case:

```
In [5]: df1['id'] == df2['id']
Out[5]: 
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
Name: id, dtype: bool
```

Id 1 is found on row 0 in both series, so you get True. Id 2 is present in both series, but never on the same row, the position never matches. Same for the `tag`:

```
In [6]: df1['tag'] == df2['tag']
Out[6]: 
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: tag, dtype: bool
```

So when you combine with `&`, only the first row matches:

```
In [7]: (df1['id'] == df2['id']) & (df1['tag'] == df2['tag'])
Out[7]: 
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

which is why the (id,tag) pair of (2,800) is not recognized as being already present.

So instead of the equality operator, you should use `merge` as suggested by the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df2,df1,on=['id','tag'],how='outer')
df3 = df3[df3.Membership_x.isna()][['id','tag','Membership_y']].rename(columns={'Membership_y':'Membership'})
df3 = df2.append(df3)
df3
```

Prints

```
id  tag Membership
0   1   700 0.5
1   2   800 0.9
2   3   600 0.8
3   3   500 0.7
4   1   800 0.9
5   2   700 0.8
```

Comment: Thanks, but it adds extra columns that I'm not interested in deleting or renaming by hands

Comment: Oh. I have handled the renaming in the code. I just tried executing again and dont see extra columns.